Building ROS bridge because of own ROS 1 msgs
I want to build the ROS1 bridge by myself and I've read the documentation.
But for the most important part I didn't find anything on the documentation, it only mentioned that you should define your ROS1 and ROS2 install space
Now my question: ROS 1 noetic is official supported till Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS2 jazzy with Ubuntu 24.04
How i could install both?
At the moment I tried to build it with a ubuntu 20.04 installed ROS noetic and with the binary Release of ROS2
But when i build it I got linking problem because of traecetools which I can't disable
I tried :
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select ros1_bridge --cmake-force-configure --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DTRACETOOLS_DISABLED=ON 

I always get
Package 'tracetools' exports library 'lttng-ust-common' which couldn't be

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llttng-ust-common
/usr/bin/ld/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : cannot find -llttng-ust-common-llttng-ust-common

Are my thoughts correct to build it like that ? I dont understand why I can't disable the tracetool, or what is the best way to build ros bridge by yourself?
